# If $|x -a| < \min\{|a|/2,\, \varepsilon a^2 /2\}$ then...

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Suppose $a \neq 0$ and $\varepsilon >0$.  If $$|x-a| < \min \left \{ \frac{|a|}{2}, \frac{\varepsilon a^2 }{2}\right \},$$
>
> then show that $x \neq 0$ and $\left |\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{a}\right| < \varepsilon$.

Proof:

Let $\delta = \min \left \{ \frac{|a|}{2}, \frac{\varepsilon a^2 }{2}\right \}$, where $\delta \leq \frac{|a|}{2}, \frac{\varepsilon a^2}{2}$ , $0< |x - a| < \delta$.

Then $|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{a}| = |\frac{a-x}{ax}|$....

I was able to solve this when x and a are fixed positive. But the question only specifies that $x,a \neq 0$.

Comment: Have you tried splitting it into cases? Maybe start with $|a|/2<\frac{\varepsilon a^2}{2}$ so that the inequality is easier to work with. Where does it lead you?

Comment: Where is x belong to?

Comment: You should really try to show some work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Case 1:** $a>0, |a|\le\varepsilon a^2$

In this particular case:

$$\varepsilon a\ge1$$

$$|x-a|<\frac a2\implies$$

$$-\frac{a}{2}<x-a<\frac a2$$

$$\frac{a}{2}<x<\frac {3a}2 \quad \\ \text{(notice: all values are positive)}$$

$$\frac{2}{a}>\frac 1x>\frac {2}{3a}$$

$$\frac{2}{a}-\frac 1a>\frac 1x-\frac 1a>\frac {2}{3a}-\frac 1a$$

$$\frac{1}{a}>\frac 1x-\frac 1a>-\frac {1}{3a}$$

$$\left|\frac 1x-\frac 1a\right|<\frac 1a=\frac
\varepsilon{a\varepsilon}\le\varepsilon$$

**Case 2:** $a>0, |a|>\varepsilon a^2$

In this particular case:

$$\varepsilon a<1$$

$$|x-a|<\frac {\varepsilon a^2}2\implies$$

$$-\frac {\varepsilon a^2}2<x-a<\frac {\varepsilon a^2}2$$

$$a-\frac {\varepsilon a^2}2<x<a+\frac {\varepsilon a^2}2\\ \text{(notice: all values are positive)}$$

$$\frac{2}{a(2-\varepsilon a)}-\frac 1a>\frac 1x-\frac 1a >\frac{2}{a(2+\varepsilon a)}-\frac 1a$$

$$\frac{\varepsilon}{2-\varepsilon a} >  \frac 1x-\frac 1a  > -\frac{\varepsilon}{2+\varepsilon a}$$

$$\frac{\varepsilon}{2-\varepsilon a} >  \left|\frac 1x-\frac 1a \right|\tag{1}$$

But $\varepsilon a<1 \implies 2-\varepsilon a>1$ or:

$$\frac1{2-\varepsilon a}<1$$

$$\frac\varepsilon{2-\varepsilon a}<\varepsilon\tag{2}$$

Combine (1) and (2) and you get:

$$\varepsilon >  \left|\frac 1x-\frac 1a \right|$$

**Case 3:** $a<0, |a|\le\varepsilon a^2$

Intorduce $b=-a$ so that $b$ is positive. In this particular case:

$$\varepsilon b>=1$$

We have to prove the following implications:

$$|x+b|<\frac b2\implies$$

$$-\frac b2<x+b<\frac b2$$

$$-b-\frac b2<x<\frac b2 - b$$

$$-\frac {3b}2<x<-\frac b2\\ \text{(notice: all numbers are negative)}$$

$$-\frac {2}{3b}+\frac 1b>\frac 1x + \frac 1b>-\frac 2b+\frac 1b$$

$$-\frac {2}{3b}+\frac 1b>\frac 1x + \frac 1b>-\frac 2b+\frac 1b$$

$$\frac {1}{3b}>\frac 1x + \frac 1b>-\frac 1b$$

$$\left|\frac 1x + \frac 1b\right|<\frac 1b=\frac {\varepsilon}{\varepsilon b}\le\varepsilon$$

$$\left|\frac 1x - \frac 1a\right|<\varepsilon$$

**Case 4:** $a<0, |a|>\varepsilon a^2$

Introduce $b=-a$ so that $b$ is positive. In this particular case:

$$\varepsilon b<1$$

We have to prove the following implications:

$$|x+b|<\frac {\varepsilon b^2}2\implies$$

$$-\frac {\varepsilon b^2}2<x+b<\frac {\varepsilon b^2}2$$

$$-b-\frac {\varepsilon b^2}2<x<-b+\frac {\varepsilon b^2}2\\ \text{(notice: all values are negative)}$$

$$-\frac{2}{b(2+\varepsilon b)}+\frac 1b>\frac 1x+\frac 1b >\frac{2}{b(-2+\varepsilon b)}+\frac 1b$$

$$\frac{\varepsilon}{2+\varepsilon b} >  \frac 1x+\frac 1b  > -\frac{\varepsilon}{2-\varepsilon b}$$

$$\left|\frac 1x+\frac 1b \right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2-\varepsilon b}\tag{3}$$

But $\varepsilon b<1 \implies 2-\varepsilon b>1$ or:

$$\frac1{2-\varepsilon b}<1$$

$$\frac\varepsilon{2-\varepsilon b}<\varepsilon\tag{4}$$

Combine (3) and (4) and you get:

$$\left|\frac 1x+\frac 1b \right|=\left|\frac 1x-\frac 1a \right|<\varepsilon$$